How to get tagName in playwright python
I want to get the tagname tagName of element selector selected by get_by_text() method
for example :
element = page.get_by_text("example", exact=True)


Why do you want this and what have you tried?

This has no use in standard playwright library usage in automation else OP clarifies the context in the question.

This is a rather unusual request, so there may be a better way to solve whatever fundamental problem you're trying to solve, but you can extract a tag from an element as follows:
element = page.get_by_text("example", exact=True)
tag_name = element.evaluate("el => el.tagName")

Complete, runnable example:
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright,expect # 1.43.0


html = '<span aria-hidden="true"><!---->Sr. Enterprise Cloud &amp; Snowflake Architect<!----></span>'


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.set_content(html)
    element = page.get_by_text("Sr. Enterprise Cloud & Snowflake Architect", exact=True)
    tag_name = element.evaluate("el => el.tagName")
    print(tag_name) # => SPAN
    browser.close()

If you're doing testing and anticipate a certain tag to be present, try:
expect(page.locator("p").locator("text='example'")).to_be_visible()

or without expect:
page.locator("p").locator("text='example'").wait_for()

Generally speaking, in testing, you don't want to care much about tag names since they're not user visible.

Thank you for your reply, but I've tested it on this element : Sr. Enterprise Cloud & Snowflake Architect
this is the code :
element = page.get_by_text("Sr. Enterprise Cloud & Snowflake Architect", exact=True)
tag_name = element.evaluate("el => el.tagName")
and still it can't match SPAN

Is there anything I'm missing ?

Can you share the actual page? That HTML works fine for me. See the update. Does my code work for you when you run it on its own? If so, then there's some site-specific behavior on your site preventing it from working, like an iframe, a shadow DOM, a cloudflare block... Please also elaborate on "can't match SPAN"--what does it do? Error, some output other than SPAN, or...? I still suggest explaining why you want to actually do this rather odd thing because there may be a much better way to do whatever it is you think you need this for.

Yeah your code works fine, even copied the actual element and still works on your code, but somehow not on mine. Anyways thank you I will figure it out

The use for this is just for filtering results of a script, that's why i m using it

I'm not sure how getting tag names is relevant to filtering results, but OK--sounds like you got this.
