In Playwright, is there - knowing its id - a way to identify the type of an element?
In Playwright, is there - knowing its id - a way to identify the HTML tag type of an element? Consider this. I know the id but want to identity its HTML tag type i.e. select or input. Can I do something like...
let typeOfTag = await page.locator(`#${id}`).type();
switch (typeOfTag){
  case "input":
    await page.locator(`#${id}`).fill(data[id]);
    break;
  case "select":
    await page.locator(`#${id}`).selectOption(data[id]);
    break;
  default:
    // none
}


Locator does have a type() method, but it's an obsolete method for emulating typing into the element, not getting its element type.

I don't see any method in the Locator documentation that's equivalent to the tagName DOM property.

See https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/4845

You can do this, but it's an antipattern. Why do you want to do this? Seems like a possible xy problem. The dupe doesn't really work though because this is JS, not Python, although .evaluate(el => el.tagName) is indeed the way to get the tag name.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78399966/how-to-get-tagname-in-playwright-python?noredirect=1&lq=1
